# SQL Server : job history group by execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

Duplicate of [SQL Server jobs history - job execution id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48650175/sql-server-jobs-history-job-execution-id)
since there's no solution yet

I need to replicate the SSMS job history. Showing only Job name, execution date, status and duration

[image: Text]

So far, tables like `sysjobhistory` have no information on how to group instances by execution.

And then there's the `sysjobactivity` table:

[image: Text]

I just don't get why the values are NULL sometimes

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Did you look at the solution given in the actual question that you link? (i.e. not posted as an answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that people always forget that SSMS does not have some special/magical insight into SQL Server.

You can find out how SSMS obtains all of the information by starting a profiler and opening Job History window.

Cut down SQL code (obtained from Profiler) is below:

```
declare @tmp_sp_help_jobhistory table( ..... )

insert into @tmp_sp_help_jobhistory 
exec msdb.dbo.sp_help_jobhistory 
    @job_id = '9c6901d0-b325-4d14-bd88-22bb50c323af',
    @mode='FULL' 

SELECT
    tshj.instance_id AS [InstanceID],
    tshj.sql_message_id AS [SqlMessageID],
    tshj.message AS [Message],

.....

FROM @tmp_sp_help_jobhistory as tshj
ORDER BY [InstanceID] ASC
```

Looking at the code of `sp_help_jobhistory` you will see that it calls `sp_help_jobhistory_full`. The SQL code is quite simple there.

Looking at the output carefully you will notice that Jobs always start at Step 1 and end at Step 0 (summary details). To generate groups numbers:

```
WITH JobData AS(
    SELECT sjh.instance_id, -- This is included just for ordering purposes
     sj.job_id,
     sj.name AS job_name,
     sjh.step_id,
     sjh.step_name,
     sjh.sql_message_id,
     sjh.sql_severity,
     sjh.message,
     sjh.run_status,
     sjh.run_date,
     sjh.run_time,
     sjh.run_duration,
     sjh.retries_attempted,
     sjh.server,
     -- Every Job has Step 1 (starting step) and Step 0 (Job outcome details)
     -- Calculate Groups based on this
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY step_id ORDER BY instance_id ) AS StepRn
    FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory AS sjh
        INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view AS sj ON sj.job_id = sjh.job_id
),
JobDataWithGroups AS(
    SELECT a.*, FirstStep.StepRn AS JobRunNumber
    FROM JobData AS a
        -- Get First Step Group Number
        CROSS APPLY( SELECT TOP 1 StepRn FROM JobData AS FirstStep WHERE FirstStep.instance_id <= a.instance_id AND FirstStep.step_id = 1 ORDER BY instance_id DESC ) AS FirstStep
)
SELECT *
FROM JobDataWithGroups
ORDER BY instance_id
```

Output
[image]

Comment: Interesting approach. Didn't know about the profiler. So this solution works when we filter with step_id = 0. Thanks